# Is it possible to use node url in NativeScript app?

Tags: node.js, nativescript, polyfills, webpack-5

Is there a way to use URL in a NS 8 + webpack 5 app?

If I do this

```js
import { URL } from 'url';

const url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

I get warning `export 'URL' (imported as 'URL') was not found in 'url' (possible exports: Url, format, parse, resolve, resolveObject)` when compiling and runtime error `url__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.URL is not a constructor`

I tried add below in webpack.config.js but doesn't help

```
  nsWebpack.chainWebpack(config => {
    config.resolve.set('fallback', { url: require.resolve('url/') });
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It might need some additional Webpack and/or TS config but could not figure out what exactly. In the end, I used an npm package to parse the URLs since I did not want to write a custom parser myself.

The best option is to use - https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-url - however, that also did not build correctly at the time of using it (NS 8.5.1, node v16.20) outputting errors in NativeScript.

Another solution is https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-url - but that uses the `URL`, so it had the same problem after all.

So, I finally used successfully the https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-parse

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using a polyfill shared in this gist https://gist.github.com/ray007/a55ceac9c7ab538ac39189943fde870f

The main purpose for me is to remove the sensitive parameters in the url, by using this polyfill, I could just do like this:

```js
private scrubRequestUrl(requestUrl: string): string {
  // Data scrubbing
  const url = new URL(requestUrl);
  url.searchParams.delete('access_token');
  return url.toString();
}
```